# functions with user inputs

Tags: function, python-3.x, pycharm

I am currently working on a BMI calculator, and i need to be able to use def functions.  However im not sure exactly how to create a def function that has user input (such as height, and weight), i know my code is wrong completely but will post it anyway.  if anyone could give me an example of such it would be greatly appreciated.  I know my functions defeat the purpose of using a function also.

```
print("BMI Calculator")
name=''
 while name != '0':
    name=input("Enter students name or '0' to quit: ")
    if name == '0':
        break
    weight=float(input('Enter students weight: '))
    height=float(input('Enter Students height in Inches:'))
    def bmi ():
        bmi = weight*703 / height ^ 2
        return bmi
    def bmi_profile():
        print('BMI Profile!')
        print('Students name:', name)
        print('Students weight: ', weight)
        print('Students height:', height)
        print('BMI Index: ', bmi)
    bmi_profile()
print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can move the user input into a function like this:

```
def user_input():
    name=input("Enter students name or '0' to quit: ")
    weight=float(input('Enter students weight: '))
    height=float(input('Enter Students height in Inches:'))
    return (name, weight, height)

name, weight, height = user_input()
```

But this way you can't quit at the user input step (in fact you *could* but it would make the code quite a bit more complex).

What I would advice you though is to use pythons object orientedness as this example somehow asks for this: I would create a class which holds the name, weight and size of the student. Additionally: to compute square use `**2`.

Here's the completely reworked code of yours using a class:

```
class BMI:
    name = None
    weight = None
    height = None

    def fill_from_input(self):
        self.name=input("Enter students name: ")
        self.weight=float(input('Enter students weight: '))
        self.height=float(input('Enter Students height in Inches:'))

    @property
    def bmi(self):
        return self.weight*703 / self.height**2

    def __repr__(self):
        return """BMI Profile!
Students name: {}
Students weight: {}
Students height: {}
BMI Index: {}""".format(self.name, self.weight, self.height, self.bmi)

while input("Ready to type in student? [Y/n]").lower() in ['y', '']:
    bmi = BMI()
    bmi.fill_from_input()
    print(bmi) # calls __repr__
print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: That's a bit overkill when you are only wanting to learn about functions. Why not just show how to pass in arguments to a plain function?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I added a simpler solution at the top

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP has a homework assignment that asks them the create a BMI function....

Comment: yeah, looks like. But I never give up hope that you could give people more on the way than they asked for

Comment: @hansaplast I am always open to learning more, this is completely harder than i thought, and i never thought it would be necessary for civil engineering.  Thank you for the help, im not sure i can use "class" but i will for sure use the top function.  thank you.

Comment: @Steven glad you can use it. If you're ok with the answer then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary things you're missing that could make this code a lot better.

**Define your functions at the beginning**

You currently have your function definitions (the blocks that start with `def`) inside your loop. That means they'll be defined every time through that loop. Instead they should be defined before the main loop begins. Consider this psuedo-code.

```
def bmi():
  # BMI code goes here

def bmi_profile():
  # Print functions go here

##### Main program goes below #####
```

**Your functions need arguments**

The "user inputs" you refer to are called arguments or parameters. They are information that gets passed into the function. Any info that your function needs, should be included in the parentheses on the `def line` here is an example for your bmi function.

```
def bmi (weight, height):
    bmi = weight * 703 / height ^ 2
    return bmi
```

See how I've included the parameters weight and height in the parentheses?

I hope that is enough to help you with this project. If you need more help, please report back, but I suspect you can get started now.